# How can I customize the TabBar indicator width and height?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using a TabBar widget and I'd like to customize the height and width of the indicator. I can't see any other property besides color I can modify.

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Give your `TabBar` a property of `isScrollable: true` if you don't want the tabs to expand to fill the screen horizontally the way they do by default.

You can use a `Container` wrapped in a `PreferredSize` to size the `TabBar`. (The `PreferredSize` is only necessary if you want it to live in the `bottom` slot of an `AppBar`.) This has the effect of making the indicators appear narrower because the `TabBar` doesn't fill the screen. However, the indicator has a hard coded height. If you don't like it, you'll have to import your own copy of [tabs.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tabs.dart) and customize the constants in that file.

Note that you can also use a `Container` to set the height of the individual `Tab`s, although that doesn't seem like what you're trying to do.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Tabs Demo'),
          bottom: new PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: new Size(200.0, 200.0),
            child: new Container(
              width: 200.0,
              child: new TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  new Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: new Tab(text: 'hello'),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: new Tab(text: 'world'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // body: ...
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: This answer definitely helped me. Cant see why its not marked as the answer. Thank you

Comment: How about setting the height of the `AppBar`? Do we have something similar to that solution?

Answer (score 52):

You can use `indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label` on the TabBar to make the indicator the same size as the label.

Or you could set the `indicator` directly, this is a `Decoration` which you can customize:

```
AppBar(
    bottom: TabBar(
        indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 5.0),
          insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:16.0)
        ),
        tabs: [
          Tab(text: 'tab 1'),
          Tab(text: 'tab 2'),
          Tab(text: 'tab 3'),
        ],
     ),
);
```

For more customisation options check this [post](https://android.jlelse.eu/flutter-bubble-tab-indicator-for-tabbar-dd038f1076d3)

Comment: What if I need to use fixed width of indicator for all the `TabBar`?

Answer (score 8):

In the same way as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273493/5938089, The best is to use containers, but I will only use one.

*For a change, I will use a bottom bar*

```
bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
    color: Colors.teal,
    child: new Container(
      height: 60.0,
      child: new TabBar(
        controller: controller,
        tabs: <Widget>[
            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.access_alarm)),
            new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.account_balance)),
        ]
      ),
    )
  ),
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K16Z.png)

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the spacing between the tabs -> **labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric (horizontal: 5),**

Answer (score 3):

You can use property `TabBar(indicatorWeight:detail Height)`.

Comment: What do you mean by `detail Height`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this in the TabBar

```
                  indicatorWeight: 0,
                  indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 0.1,
                      color: AppColor.themeColor,
                    ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Tab Indicator Styler](https://pub.dev/packages/tab_indicator_styler) package for more advanced styling.

Answer (score 0):

```
appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("TabBar demo"),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: new TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.red),
                insets: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
              ),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              isScrollable: true,
              onTap: (index) {
                print(index);
                _currentIndex = index;
                setState(() {});
              },
              tabs: [
                new Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 80,
                  // color: Colors.red,
                  child: new Tab(text: '1'),
                ),
                new Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 80,
                  // color: Colors.red,
                  child: new Tab(text: '222'),
                ),
                new Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 80,
                  // color: Colors.red,
                  child: new Tab(text: '333333'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // body: ...
    );
```

Comment: give tabs item fixed width,and set  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you decrease default tab bar size use SizeBox().

```
                             SizedBox(
                                  height: 40,
                                  child: TabBar(
                                      isScrollable: true,
                                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                                      labelColor: Colors.black,
                                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),

                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                          color: AppTheme().orange),
                                      tabs: getTab(),
                                      controller: _tabController),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating WhatsApp like tabbar you can `isScrollable: true` for TabBar then get the width of the screen and calculate the width for 3 tabs other than camera(now community), then wrap your 3 `Tab` widget inside `SizedBox` with calculated width. Here's the code

```
//get screen size
static Size screen =
      MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).size;

// Calculate common width for 3 tabs
final double screenWidth = Data.screen.width;
final tabWidth = screenWidth / 4.8; // works for 6.5inch display

List<Widget> myTabs = [
      const HomePageTab(
        icon: Icons.groups_rounded,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: tabWidth,
        child: const HomePageTab(
          title: 'Chats',
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: tabWidth,
        child: const HomePageTab(
          title: 'Status',
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: tabWidth,
        child: const HomePageTab(
          title: 'Calls',
        ),
      ),
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set
`indicatorWeight: 0` in TabBar. If you want tab as rounded container, here is an example:

```
TabBar(
    indicator: ShapeDecoration(
     color: Colors.white,
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
      ),
     ),
    indicatorWeight: 0,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can design the underline indicator with `border-radius`, and the length of the indicator according to the text container length.

```
child: TabBar(
    indicatoenter code herer: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: widgetBlueColor,
    ),
    indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 33, bottom: 2),
    labelColor: widgetBlueColor,
    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black87,
    labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
    labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    tabs: const [
        Tab(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 60,
                child: Text(
                    "DETAILS",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        Tab(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 85,
                child: Text(
                    "DOCUMENTS",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
            )
        )
    ]
)
```