# Text of tab is partially hidden when switched to another tab in TabBarView, flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Please tell me how to remove this hiding of attempted in TabBar. I used container to give size, but it's not changing the size of tab. I think by using indicatorsize, it can be done, but not sure how and which method is best for these cases.

[image]

Here is the code -

```
bottom: TabBar(
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: [
              Container(
                width: 100,
                child: const Tab(
                  text: 'Attempted',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 120,
                child: const Tab(
                  text: 'Booked',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 80,
                child: const Tab(
                  text: 'Travelled',
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                child: const Tab(
                  text: 'Cancelled',
                ),
              ),
            ],
            controller: _tabController,
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239291/how-to-customize-tabbar-width-in-flutter

Answer (score 2):

Your first tab text **Attempted** is longer than the **width** of **Container** and won't fit in your container.
you can delete all container widget and use **FittedBox** widget like this.

```
tabs: const [
            FittedBox(
              child: Tab(
                text: 'Attempted',
              ),
            ),
            FittedBox(
              child: Tab(
                text: 'Booked',
              ),
            ),
            FittedBox(
              child: Tab(
                text: 'Travelled',
              ),
            ),
            FittedBox(
              child: Tab(
                text: 'Cancelled',
              ),
            ),
          ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **isScrollable** property

```
  TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: []
          )
```