# Flutter - how can i set the height of a TabBar?

Tags: flutter

I want to resize my TabBar because default height is too much, how can achieve it? Thanks.

```
DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Text('Tab 1'),
            Text('Tab 2'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.apps),
          Icon(Icons.apps),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize the TabBar indicator width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272440/how-can-i-customize-the-tabbar-indicator-width-and-height)

Comment: Is it the TabBar or the TabBarView that you want to adjust the height of?

Answer (score 8):

For TabBar widget you can do as @praveenb suggested

```
child: TabBar(
  ...
  tabs: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      child: Tab(
      ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [PreferredSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html):

```
DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
          child: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Text('Tab 1'),
                Text('Tab 2'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.apps),
            Icon(Icons.apps),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

It will change overall height of the appbar but if you want to change the height of the tabbar only then apply the **PreferredSize widget** to the **TabBar widget** widget rather than applying it on the **AppBar widget**.

Comment: for TabBar widget PreferredSize not worked, but SizedBox(height: 58, child: //some widget ) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `height` of `Tab` like this:

```
          TabBar(
            ...
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                text: '1',
                height: 32,
              ),
              Tab(
                text: '2',
                height: 32,
              ),
            ],
          )
```